# How to modify (prototype?) methods of native Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

Are there any examples of them?

Comment: For future reference, don't type your question in all-caps.

Answer (score 2):

the following script adds a method of `contains` in the string prototype in javascript, similarly you can add more methods as you like.

**Usage**

```
var myName = "ZainShaikh";
if (myName.contains("zain", true)) { // this condition will be true, because of ignorecase parameter
     alert('yuppie, this is my name.');
 }
 else {
     alert('awww, this is not my name.');
}
```

**Prototype Method**

```
String.prototype.contains = function(value, ignorecase) {
    if (ignorecase) {
        return (this.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1);
    }
    else {
        return this.indexOf(value) != -1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

YOU CAN READ UP ON IT AT http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: your link is about `XmlHttpRequest`. :s